Failed to notify dependency resolution listener importing old project
I am getting this error while importing old project
Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
'void org.gradle.api.artifacts.DependencySubstitutions$Substitution.with(org.gradle.api.artifacts.component.ComponentSelector)'


Exception is:
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
'void org.gradle.api.artifacts.DependencySubstitutions$Substitution.with(org.gradle.api.artifacts.component.ComponentSelector)'
at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.addModels(GradleModelFetchAction.java:183)



build.gradle
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.4'
    
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}

 repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    
}


How did you fix it? I'm faced with the same error.
